# How to Create Dynamic List Based on Certain Values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have an excel Sheet Contain Data like below
[image: ExcelSheet]

I need to Create Different List based on two Dropdowns, One of Item for eg 100m,200m and another of Section like Senior Boys,Male Etc
How To Achieve this  , I am new to Excel

I was able to make dropdowns using data Validations,

Comment: Do you mean a Pivot Table?

Comment: May be , I need a list of each item section wise, One person can participate in 3 items

Comment: Create a table with slicers?

Comment: This is hard to do with Excel 2007/2010 and insanely easier to do if you have Excel 2021 or Excel O365.